# React Native: Passing nested array to another screen and output in flatlist

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to pass a nested data between two screens in my app. The screens: `MemberListScreen.js` and `MemberDetailsScreen.js`.

- The `dummy.js` is the data that I'm trying to output.
- The `MemberListItem.js` is the `Flatlist` that is going to be used in `MemberListScreen.js`.

The user will start at `MemberListScreen.js`. This is where the `Flatlist` will show `memberName` data from the array. When the user click on one of the `item`, it will direct to `MemberDetailsScreen.js` and the `companyPortfolioImage` data will be shown in another `Flstlist`.   I got this error when I go to `MemberDetailsScreen.js` : `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'MemberData.companyPortfolioImage.potId')`. I use version 6.0.10 of react-navigation/native and 6.6.1 of react-navigation/native-stack

dummy.js

```
export const MemberData = [
    {
        memberId: 5,
        memberName: "Champion",
        companyPortfolioImage: [
            {
                potId: 1,
                potImage:'https://d1csarkz8obe9u.cloudfront.net/posterpreviews/business-event-banner-design-template-392070a11089eb5fb736443db6abef83_screen.jpg?ts=1618400029'
            },
        ]
    }, 
];
```

MemberListItem.js

```
export const MemberCell = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    const renderItem = ({item}) => (
        <TouchableOpacity style={[GlobalStyle.MemberListContainer]} activeOpacity={0.8} onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('MemberDetailsScreen', {memberData: item});}}>
            <View>
                <Text style={[GlobalStyle.MemberListName]}>{item.memberName}</Text>
            </View> 
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )

    return (
        <FlatList 
            scrollEnabled={true}
            numColumns={2}
            data={MemberData}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={MemberData => MemberData.memberId}
        />
    );

}
```

MemberListScreen.js

```
const MembersListScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    return (
        <View  style={[GlobalStyle.GrayScrollView]}>  
            <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <MemberCell/>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

MemberDetailsScreen.js

```
const MemberDetailsScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {
    const { memberData } = route.params;

    const Portfolio = () => {
        
        return (
            <View style={{width: '100%', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <View style={[GlobalStyle.CompanyPortfolioContainer]}>
                    <Image style={[GlobalStyle.CompanyPortfolioImage]} source={{uri: memberData.companyPortfolioImage.potImage}} resizeMode="cover" />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
        
    }

    return (
        <ScrollView  style={[GlobalStyle.GrayScrollView]}>      
            <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <View style={[GlobalStyle.MemberInfoContainer]}> 
                    <Text style={[GlobalStyle.MemberDetailName]}>{memberData.memberName}</Text>
                </View>
             
                <View style={[GlobalStyle.MemberInfoContainer, {marginBottom: 10}]}>
                    <FlatList
                        scrollEnabled={false}
                        data={memberData.companyPortfolioImage}
                        renderItem={Portfolio} 
                        keyExtractor={memberData=> memberData.companyPortfolioImage.potId}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
}
```

Comment: All looks correct, but are you sure this `companyPortfolioImage.potId` exist in your data? Check spelling..

Comment: @iphonic are you referring to the `keyExtractor={MemberData => MemberData.companyPortfolioImage.potId}` ? I checked the spelling and change the `MemberData` to `memberData`. It still doesn't work

Comment: Can you double check if memberData exists inside route.param?

Comment: @caslawter memberData does exist. I'm able to output `memberName`. Only the `companyPortfolioImage` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the state from route.params, you can try to pass it in as props in your renderItem.

```
const Portfolio = ({potId, potImage}) => {
    
    return (
        <View style={{width: '100%', alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <View style={[GlobalStyle.CompanyPortfolioContainer]}>
                <Image style={[GlobalStyle.CompanyPortfolioImage]} source={{uri: potImage}} resizeMode="cover" />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
    
}
```

Comment: I need route.params because the `companyPortfolioImage` data came from another screen. Even if I pass it in as props in renderItem what should I update in the `<FlatList/>`? The error came from there.